# Firebase Google auth ErrorUncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_initializationPromise')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-oauth

following documentation for firebase but having this error redirect.ts:101 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_initializationPromise')

```html
import { useContext, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { GoogleAuthProvider,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signInWithRedirect,
     } from "firebase/auth";

import {auth} from '../firebase';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
        const [user, setUser] = useState({});

        const googleSignIn = (auth) => {
            const provider =  new GoogleAuthProvider();
            return signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
                       
        } 

        const logOut = () => {
            signOut(auth)
        }

        useEffect(()=> {
            const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth,(currentUser) =>{
                setUser(currentUser);
                console.log('User', currentUser);
            })
            return () => {
                unsubscribe();
            }
        }, []);


    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ googleSignIn, logOut, user }}>
            {/* not loading then show the children */}
            {children} 
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```